# Filter mat table using multiple values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using angular material table and my sample data will be like below

```
 const dataSet = [
      {
        name: 'User1',
        standard: '10 A',
        subjects: ['biology', 'physics']
      },
      {
        name: 'User2',
        standard: '10 B',
        subjects: ['maths', 'physics']
      },
      {
        name: 'User3',
        standard: '9 A',
        subjects: []
      },
      {
        name: 'User4',
        standard: '3 A',
        subjects: ['biology']
      },
      {
        name: 'User5',
        standard: '3 A',
        subjects: []
      }
    ];
```

am setting the data source for the table as given below

```
this.datasource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(dataSet );
```

I have to implement filter which have combination of standard filter and  subjects filter

One filter inputs will be ,

```
const filter = {
    standard: ['10' , '9'],
    subjects: ['maths', 'nosubjects']
}
```

and the expected output will be

```
const resultDataSet= [
      {
        name: 'User2',
        standard: '10 B',
        subjects: ['maths', 'physics']
      },

      {
        name: 'User3',
        standard: '9 A',
        subjects: []
      }
    ];
```

nosubjects meaning students with no subjects allocated,

`this.datasource.filter` for mat table only takes single search key. How can we implemented this custom filter in mat table? If not possible array.filter method also fine.

Comment: What is the filter supposed to do? What is the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Expected output updated in the question. Basically the new data set which match all the conditions in filter.

Comment: can you create stackblitz ?

Comment: Is this what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/on87m4xg/ ?